# Method Database\Factories\TagQuestionFactory::factory does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have a Laravel Factory named `TagQuestionFactory` which goes like this:

```
public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'tag_id' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1,50),
            'que_id' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1,50),
        ];
    }
```

And in **DatabaseSeeder**, I added this:

```
public function run()
    {
        TagQuestionFactory::factory(50)->create();
    }
```

Then I run `php artisan db:seed` but returns this error:

> BadMethodCallException
>
> **Method Database\Factories\TagQuestionFactory::factory does not exist.**

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Use `(new TagQuestionFactory())->create()`, the `factory` method is used from the model

Answer (score 1):

you should call the factory form the model like this

```
public function run()
{
    TagQuestion::factory(50)->create();
}
```

or you can call it directly like this

```
public function run()
{
    TagQuestionFactory::times(50)->create();
}
```